# How can i modulo a big integer value

Tags: c++, modulo, long-long

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    #include "md5.h"

    int main()
    {
        MD5 md5;

        string message = "secretU";
        char arr[message.size()];
        strcpy(arr, message.c_str());

        //encrypting the message "secretU", it will return a string of hexadecimals
        string result = md5.digestString(arr); 

        //print the result of the encrypted message.
        cout << result; 
        return 0;
    }
```

Result of the output in hexadecimals

```
1853c517b0e1095a341210f1a4b422e6
```

Once i tried to convert to Decimal, it needs 125 bit size? However, unsigned long long can only contain up to 64 bits, is there a way to store this long integer so that i can **modulo** it with the value i want?

Convert hexadecimals to decimal

```
32336430049777443053240099092194140902
```

Comment: You don't need the temporary array `arr`. Either use `message.c_str()` or (if the `digestString` modifies the contents) `&message[0]`. Or modify the function to accept a `std::string` object?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by hand or use a library that provides big integers like https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Answer (score 2):

Take the modulo by breaking them into pieces.. say for example you want to take modulo of **37^11 mod 77** in which 37^11 gives answer **1.77917621779460E17** so to get this .. take some small number in place of 11 which gives an integer value.. break it into pieces... **37^11 mod 77** can be written as **(37^4 x 37^4 x 37^3 mod 77)** so solve it as.. **{(37^4 mod 77)(37^4 mod 77)(37^3 mod 77)} mod 77**. So, in general **xy mod n = {(x mod n)(y mod n)} mod n**